# RCP Eclipse Model Window

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am building a RCP application using SWT/Jface and stuck at a point where I need to open a model/window/popup on a perspective action.

I want to open a model/popup/window(having ok/cancel button only) from a perspective listener and wants the control to wait for the model/popup/window ok/cancel button response  and  executes the popup/model/window listner ........ and than the perspective listener logic complete.

It is like forcing the perspective control to wait for the popup/model/window action to complete.

Any suggestions will be very helful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want a modal `Dialog`. Here is the interesting part from the documentation of `Shell`:

> The modality of an instance may be specified using style bits. The modality style bits are used to determine whether input is blocked for other shells on the display. The `PRIMARY_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to its parent. **The `APPLICATION_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to every other shell in the display**. The `SYSTEM_MODAL` style allows an instance to block input to all shells, including shells belonging to different applications.

So just create a JFace `Dialog` using [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html) tutorial and create a new instance of it using `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` as the style bit.